# Python : Join 2 tables based on partial text match in both the tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have 2 tables - Description and Part. I want to extract the relevant Repair code and type based on the data in the description table. Also, I want to fetch how many matches are there for each row in the description.If there is more than one match, the output table should contain all the respective matches.

Below is the example:

Description table is as follows:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|         **Description**                                   |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  Special Charges Parts Special Parts                      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  Misc. Charges Chairs broken and Table Handle Repair      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  Misc. Charges Table Repair                               |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  Special Charges Spare Parts                              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  VAT Charges Additional                                   |  
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

The code table is as follows:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      **Code**       |     **Type**     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|  Special Charges    | Special Parts    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|  Special Charges    | Administrative   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|  Misc. Charges      | Chair Repair     | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|  Misc. Charges      | Table Handle     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Required output :

```
|---------------------------------------------------|-----------------|--------------|---------------|
|         **Description**                           |    **Code**     |  **Type**    |** # Matches** |
|---------------------------------------------------|-----------------|------------- |---------------|  
|Special Charges Parts Special Parts                | Special Charges |Special Parts |   1           |   
|---------------------------------------------------|-----------------|--------------|---------------|
|Misc. Charges Chair broken and Table Handle Repair | Misc. Charges   |Chair Repair  |   2           | 
|---------------------------------------------------|-----------------|--------------|---------------|
|Misc. Charges Chair broken and Table Handle Repair | Misc. Charges   |Table Handle  |   2           | 
|---------------------------------------------------|-----------------|--------------|---------------|
|Misc. Charges Table Handle                         | Misc. Charges   |Table Handle  |   1           | 
|---------------------------------------------------|-----------------|--------------|---------------|
|Special Charges Spare Parts              |         | Special Charges |              |   0           |               
|---------------------------------------------------|-----------------|--------------|---------------|
|VAT Charges Additional                             |                 |              |   0           | 
|---------------------------------------------------|-----------------|--------------|---------------|
```

Here are the input dataframes:

Description = {'Description':['Special Charges Parts Special Parts','Misc. Charges Chairs broken and Table Handle Repair','Misc. Charges Table Repair','Special Charges Spare Parts','VAT Charges Additional']}

Description = pd.DataFrame(Description)

Code = {'Code':['Special Charges','Special Charges','Misc. Charges','Misc. Charges'],'Type':['Special Parts','Administrative','Chair Repair','Table Handle']}

Code= pd.DataFrame(Code)

Comment: Please provide the people you want help from with the necessary setup steps. Busy developers probably don't have time to construct dataframes from these tables.

Comment: Thank you for the advise.. Just added them